# A generic function in C++ to print 2D integer array, created by various techniques

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a function in C++ to print 2D integer array created by various mechanisms allowed in C++. Please refer the comments in the code I have pasted below for the different techniques I used to create 2D integer array.

```
#include<iostream>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4
using namespace std;

void printMatrix(int **mat)
{
    cout<<"\n Printing Matrix : \n";
    for(int i=0 ; i<=ROW-1 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<=COL-1 ; j++)
            cout<< *(*(mat+i)+j)<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Method 1 - Creation of 2D Matrix using Square Braces
    int mat1[][COL] = { {34,36,31,39},
                        {12,19,13,17},
                        {28,24,26,23},  };

    // Method 2 - Creation of 2D Matrix using new operator
    int **mat2 = new int*[ROW]();
    for(int i=0 ; i<=ROW-1 ; i++)
        mat2[i] = new int[COL]();

    //printMatrix((int **)mat1);   
    //Uncommenting above line throws exception "Access Violation while reading location!"
    printMatrix(mat2);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The printMatrix() function should be able to print mat1 as well as mat2.
How to go about this?

Comment: You'll need to override the print matrix function. int mat[][COL] will be one contiguous memory bock accessible by int* while your other matrix is an array of pointers to int (i,e int**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making your function a template function you could solve the problem:

```
template<typename T>
void printMatrix(T mat) {
    cout<<"\n Printing Matrix : \n";
    for(int i=0 ; i<=ROW-1 ; i++) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<=COL-1 ; j++)
            cout<< *(*(mat+i)+j)<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeea6047025d45b9)

However this would work only for 3x4 arrays, since you hard-coded the dimensions in macro defines.

For the general case however, you can't treat concrete 2D arrays the same with heap allocated 2D arrays, because except from being different types, for the first you can have dimensional information while for the second you can't. Consequently, you would have to treat them differently.

For example for a 2d array you could do the following template function:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void print_array(int (&A)[N][M]) {
  for(std::size_t i(0); i < N; ++i) {
    for(std::size_t j(0); j < M; ++j)
      std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
  }
}
```

But for a dynamically allocated array you would need its dimensions to iterate through it:

```
void print_array(int **a, std::size_t N, std::size_t M) {
  for(std::size_t i(0); i < N; ++i) {
    for(std::size_t j(0); j < M; ++j)
      std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
  }
}
```

So for arbitrary dimension arrays you would end up with the following generic function to treat both of them (i.e, you have to pass the dimensions):

```
template<typename T>
void printMatrix(T mat, std::size_t N, std::size_t M) {
    cout<<"\n Printing Matrix : \n";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < N; ++j)
            cout<< *(*(mat+i)+j)<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

You could however, use STL containers and in particular a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to replace both 2D arrays and 2D dynamically allocated arrays in your code. By overloading the `operator<<` for it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, std::vector<std::vector<int>> const&v) {
  for(auto &&i : v) {
    for(auto &&j : i) out << j << " ";
    out << std::endl;
  }
  return out;
}
```

you could print your `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (e.g., `vv`) as:

```
std::cout << vv << std::endl;
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95f489ea2d218f88)

Comment: Hello 42 :), Thanks. I was curious if there is a reason you chose 'typename' over 'class' ?

Comment: No particular reason, after all in this particular context they're equivalent.

Comment: Yep.. It is.. Thank you.. For the printMatrix() problem, yours was precisely the one I was searching for... Furthermore +100 for Live Demo :)